# How to make this table fit on a landscape page?

Tags: tables, landscape

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\everymath{\displaystyle} 

\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}

\begin{document}

    \begin{landscape}
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Add caption}
        \begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
        \toprule
        Dependent variable: & $CoJPoD_{sov \ system|sov}$ &       & $\Delta CoJPoD_{sov \ system|sov}$ &       & $CoJPoD_{sov|sov \ system}$ &       & $CoJPoD_{bank \ system|sov}$ &       & $\Delta CoJPoD_{bank \ system|sov}$ &       & $CoJPoD_{sov|bank \ system}$ &  \\
        \midrule
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
              & \textbf{(1)} & \textbf{(2)} & \textbf{(3)} & \textbf{(4)} & \textbf{(5)} & \textbf{(6)} & (7)   & (8)   & (9)   & (10)  & (11)  & (12) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        Constant & -11.116*** & -10.212*** & -6.668*** & -5.740*** & 13.194*** & 13.903*** & -7.270*** & -7.551*** & -6.224*** & -6.290*** & 16.927*** & 17.078*** \\
              & (-2.975) & (-3.600) & (-2.980) & (-3.000) & (3.634) & (3.570) & (-2.607) & (-2.931) & (-2.907) & (-3.312) & (4.759) & (3.880) \\
        Market Ret (6 months rolling) (\%) & 0.001*** &       & 0.001*** &       & 0.000 &       & 0.000 &       & 0.000* &       & -0.000* &  \\
              & (3.065) &       & (3.696) &       & (-0.016) &       & (1.086) &       & (1.652) &       & (-1.862) &  \\
        Market Vol (6 months rolling) (\%) & 0.008 &       & 0.009 &       & 0.008 &       & -0.008 &       & -0.002 &       & -0.001 &  \\
              & (0.696) &       & (1.143) &       & (0.464) &       & (-1.049) &       & (-0.301) &       & (-0.083) &  \\
        Market Ret (1 month avg) (\%) &       & 0.025*** &       & 0.020*** &       & -0.020** &       & 0.011** &       & 0.012*** &       & -0.029** \\
              &       & (3.235) &       & (3.606) &       & (-2.118) &       & (2.283) &       & (3.247) &       & (-2.530) \\
        Market Vol (1 month avg) (\%) &       & -0.020*** &       & -0.017*** &       & 0.001 &       & -0.010*** &       & -0.006*** &       & 0.004 \\
              &       & (-4.329) &       & (-5.025) &       & (0.105) &       & (-3.444) &       & (-2.804) &       & (0.449) \\
        Log GDP & 0.913*** & 0.840*** & 0.550*** & 0.475*** & -1.180*** & -1.239*** & 0.602** & 0.626*** & 0.522*** & 0.529*** & -1.492*** & -1.505*** \\
              & (2.922) & (3.529) & (2.960) & (3.008) & (-3.878) & (-3.778) & (2.570) & (2.893) & (2.913) & (3.324) & (-4.890) & (-3.976) \\
        Debt/GDP (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.004*** & 0.002** & 0.002** & 0.004* & 0.004* & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.002** & 0.002** & 0.003 & 0.003 \\
              & (2.836) & (2.861) & (1.981) & (1.975) & (1.775) & (1.764) & (2.657) & (2.689) & (2.062) & (2.075) & (1.540) & (1.566) \\
        Reserve/Debt (\%) & 0.069** & 0.071** & 0.043** & 0.045** & 0.075** & 0.073** & 0.051*** & 0.053*** & 0.036*** & 0.037*** & 0.057** & 0.055** \\
              & (2.512) & (2.372) & (2.130) & (1.964) & (2.405) & (2.367) & (2.974) & (3.099) & (2.746) & (2.803) & (2.204) & (2.202) \\
        Term Spread (\%) & 0.042*** & 0.042*** & 0.038*** & 0.037*** & 0.012 & 0.015** & 0.012*** & 0.010*** & 0.009*** & 0.008*** & -0.003 & -0.002 \\
              & (6.331) & (6.990) & (7.131) & (7.323) & (1.330) & (1.985) & (4.036) & (4.962) & (3.790) & (5.111) & (-0.248) & (-0.186) \\
        VSTOXX (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.004*** & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.008*** & 0.008*** & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.001*** & 0.001*** & 0.007*** & 0.007*** \\
              & (4.920) & (4.380) & (4.450) & (3.916) & (7.650) & (8.089) & (6.285) & (6.200) & (3.514) & (3.497) & (5.211) & (6.388) \\
              &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
        Bank fixed effects & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \\
        No. of observations & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620 \\
        Adjusted R\^2 & 0.728 & 0.720 & 0.774 & 0.761 & 0.822 & 0.822 & 0.718 & 0.721 & 0.772 & 0.774 & 0.784 & 0.785 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%

    \end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can fit this table nicely on a landscape A4 page? For the current code, columns (7) onwards does not fit onto the page. I have tried `\scalebox` however that makes the numbers so small that it's barely readable. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: Please always post _complete_ document starting with `\documentclass`. In particular without knowing your documentclass and options we don't know the size of a landscape page so can't test any suggested changes.

Comment: In the actual format, simply is too wide even for a landscape page with margins of 1 cm and a tiny font. Consider change the headers to obtain more  narrowed columns, round numbers and so on.

Comment: Get rid of the stars and use colors to highlight entries. Also, depending on the meaning of the numbers, you can use small pie charts (maybe with color) or other graphic representations. Huge tables of numbers are almost useless for conveying ideas (but work as lookup medium). Depending on what you want to *say* with all these values, it may also be more useful to have a couple of "digest" plots/charts that highlight the important features of the data.

Comment: A minor, off-topic question: Should one of the independent variables be labelled "Log GDP" or "$\Delta$ Log GDP"?

Comment: @Mico It is Log GDP :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This makes it fit, I fixed the headings to use a correct font (never set multi-letter words in math italic) but then I commented out the whole heading. The column widths were dominated by the heading widths. Obviously you need some heading but I don't have the subject knowledge to suggest alternative heading layout.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pdflscape,array,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1pt}
\footnotesize
% Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
\vspace*{-1.5cm}
  \caption{Add caption}
    \hspace*{-5pt}\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{2.2cm}cccccccccccc}
    \toprule
%     Dependent variable: &
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{$CoJPoD_{\mathrm{{sov \ system|sov}}}$}&
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta CoJPoD_{\mathrm{sov \ system|sov}}$}&
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{$CoJPoD_{\mathrm{sov|sov \ system}}$}&
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{$CoJPoD_{\mathrm{bank \ system|sov}}$}&
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta CoJPoD_{\mathrm{bank \ system|sov}}$}&
%\multicolumn{2}{c}{$CoJPoD_{\mathrm{sov|bank \ system}}$}\\
%    \midrule
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
          & \textbf{(1)} & \textbf{(2)} & \textbf{(3)} & \textbf{(4)} & \textbf{(5)} & \textbf{(6)} & (7)   & (8)   & (9)   & (10)  & (11)  & (12) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Constant & -11.116*** & -10.212*** & -6.668*** & -5.740*** & 13.194*** & 13.903*** & -7.270*** & -7.551*** & -6.224*** & -6.290*** & 16.927*** & 17.078*** \\
          & (-2.975) & (-3.600) & (-2.980) & (-3.000) & (3.634) & (3.570) & (-2.607) & (-2.931) & (-2.907) & (-3.312) & (4.759) & (3.880) \\
    Market Ret (6 months rolling) (\%) & 0.001*** &       & 0.001*** &       & 0.000 &       & 0.000 &       & 0.000* &       & -0.000* &  \\
          & (3.065) &       & (3.696) &       & (-0.016) &       & (1.086) &       & (1.652) &       & (-1.862) &  \\
    Market Vol (6 months rolling) (\%) & 0.008 &       & 0.009 &       & 0.008 &       & -0.008 &       & -0.002 &       & -0.001 &  \\
          & (0.696) &       & (1.143) &       & (0.464) &       & (-1.049) &       & (-0.301) &       & (-0.083) &  \\
    Market Ret (1 month avg) (\%) &       & 0.025*** &       & 0.020*** &       & -0.020** &       & 0.011** &       & 0.012*** &       & -0.029** \\
          &       & (3.235) &       & (3.606) &       & (-2.118) &       & (2.283) &       & (3.247) &       & (-2.530) \\
    Market Vol (1 month avg) (\%) &       & -0.020*** &       & -0.017*** &       & 0.001 &       & -0.010*** &       & -0.006*** &       & 0.004 \\
          &       & (-4.329) &       & (-5.025) &       & (0.105) &       & (-3.444) &       & (-2.804) &       & (0.449) \\
    Log GDP & 0.913*** & 0.840*** & 0.550*** & 0.475*** & -1.180*** & -1.239*** & 0.602** & 0.626*** & 0.522*** & 0.529*** & -1.492*** & -1.505*** \\
          & (2.922) & (3.529) & (2.960) & (3.008) & (-3.878) & (-3.778) & (2.570) & (2.893) & (2.913) & (3.324) & (-4.890) & (-3.976) \\
    Debt/GDP (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.004*** & 0.002** & 0.002** & 0.004* & 0.004* & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.002** & 0.002** & 0.003 & 0.003 \\
          & (2.836) & (2.861) & (1.981) & (1.975) & (1.775) & (1.764) & (2.657) & (2.689) & (2.062) & (2.075) & (1.540) & (1.566) \\
    Reserve/Debt (\%) & 0.069** & 0.071** & 0.043** & 0.045** & 0.075** & 0.073** & 0.051*** & 0.053*** & 0.036*** & 0.037*** & 0.057** & 0.055** \\
          & (2.512) & (2.372) & (2.130) & (1.964) & (2.405) & (2.367) & (2.974) & (3.099) & (2.746) & (2.803) & (2.204) & (2.202) \\
    Term Spread (\%) & 0.042*** & 0.042*** & 0.038*** & 0.037*** & 0.012 & 0.015** & 0.012*** & 0.010*** & 0.009*** & 0.008*** & -0.003 & -0.002 \\
          & (6.331) & (6.990) & (7.131) & (7.323) & (1.330) & (1.985) & (4.036) & (4.962) & (3.790) & (5.111) & (-0.248) & (-0.186) \\
    VSTOXX (\%) & 0.004*** & 0.004*** & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.008*** & 0.008*** & 0.003*** & 0.003*** & 0.001*** & 0.001*** & 0.007*** & 0.007*** \\
          & (4.920) & (4.380) & (4.450) & (3.916) & (7.650) & (8.089) & (6.285) & (6.200) & (3.514) & (3.497) & (5.211) & (6.388) \\
          &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &       &  \\
    Bank fixed effects & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes   & Yes \\
    No. of observations & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620   & 620 \\
    Adjusted R\^2 & 0.728 & 0.720 & 0.774 & 0.761 & 0.822 & 0.822 & 0.718 & 0.721 & 0.772 & 0.774 & 0.784 & 0.785 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\hspace*{-5pt}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}%
\end{table}%

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, this is a great solution, I will actually just omit the headings and put it in a footnote or somewhere, thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my attempt to make the table fit into the text block. Some of the most important changes I made are:

- Change font size to `\footnotesize` (`9pt` in this case)
- Reduce `\tabcolsep` (which governs intercolumn white space) from `6pt` to `3.5pt`
- Shorten labels in first column
- Replace ***, **, and * with superscript asterisks (more economical spacewise)

Other important changes:

- Use the `dcolumn` package and the `D` column type to align numbers on decimal points
- Use `rotating` package and `sidewaystable` environment instead of `lscape`
- Use text italics rather than math italics for 'CoJPoD', typeset the associated subscript material in upright text font.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twoside, a4paper, 11pt]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{natbib}
%\def\pgfsysdriver{pgfsys-dvipdfm.def}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, arrows}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[update,prepend]{epstopdf}
%\usepackage{mathpazo}
%\usepackage{eulervm}
%\usepackage{iwona}
\usepackage[pdftex,colorlinks,linkcolor=blue,citecolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}

\setlength{\textwidth}{6.5in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0in}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 0.5ex minus 0.2ex}

\linespread{1.5}

\usepackage[vmargin=2.5cm, hmargin=2cm]{geometry}

\raggedbottom

\everymath{\displaystyle} 

\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}

% new code:
\usepackage{rotating}
\renewcommand\textfraction{.1}
\newcommand{\CoJPoD}{\textit{CoJPoD}}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\newcommand{\mc}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand{\astiii}{^{***}}
\newcommand{\astii}{^{**}}
\newcommand{\asti}{^{*}}
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3.5pt}
\begin{document}

%\begin{landscape}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
%\begin{table}[htbp]
\footnotesize   
      \caption{Add caption}
\begin{tabular}{@{}l *{12}{D{.}{.}{6}}@{}}
\toprule
Indep.\ variables & \multicolumn{12}{c@{}}{Dependent variables}\\
\cmidrule(l){2-13}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$\CoJPoD_{(\text{sov system}|\text{sov})}$} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta \CoJPoD_{(\text{sov system}|\text{sov})}$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\CoJPoD_{(\text{sov}|\text{sov  system})}$} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\CoJPoD_{(\text{bank system}|\text{sov})}$} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\Delta \CoJPoD_{(\text{bank system}|\text{sov}}$} &  
\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\CoJPoD_{(\text{sov}|\text{bank system})}$} \\
\midrule
\\
&\mc{\textbf{(1)}} &\mc{\textbf{(2)}} & \mc{\textbf{(3)}} 
&\mc{\textbf{(4)}} &\mc{\textbf{(5)}} & \mc{\textbf{(6)}} 
&\mc{\textbf{(7)}} &\mc{\textbf{(8)}} & \mc{\textbf{(9)}} 
&\mc{\textbf{(10)}}&\mc{\textbf{(11)}}&\mc{\textbf{(12)}}\\
\\
Constant & -11.116\astiii & -10.212\astiii & -6.668\astiii & -5.740\astiii & 13.194\astiii & 13.903\astiii & -7.270\astiii & -7.551\astiii & -6.224\astiii & -6.290\astiii & 16.927\astiii & 17.078\astiii \\
      & (-2.975) & (-3.600) & (-2.980) & (-3.000) & (3.634) & (3.570) & (-2.607) & (-2.931) & (-2.907) & (-3.312) & (4.759) & (3.880) \\
Market Ret   & 0.001\astiii &       & 0.001\astiii &       & 0.000 &       & 0.000 &       & 0.000\asti &       & -0.000\asti &  \\
\ \ (6 mo rolling)& (3.065) &       & (3.696) &       & (-0.016) &       & (1.086) &       & (1.652) &       & (-1.862) &  \\
Market Vol   & 0.008 &       & 0.009 &       & 0.008 &       & -0.008 &       & -0.002 &       & -0.001 &  \\
\ \ (6 mo rolling)      & (0.696) &       & (1.143) &       & (0.464) &       & (-1.049) &       & (-0.301) &       & (-0.083) &  \\
Market Ret   &       & 0.025\astiii &       & 0.020\astiii &       & -0.020\astii &       & 0.011\astii &       & 0.012\astiii &       & -0.029\astii \\
\ \ (1 mo avg)      &       & (3.235) &       & (3.606) &       & (-2.118) &       & (2.283) &       & (3.247) &       & (-2.530) \\
Market Vol   &       & -0.020\astiii &       & -0.017\astiii &       & 0.001 &       & -0.010\astiii &       & -0.006\astiii &       & 0.004 \\
\ \ (1 mo avg)      &       & (-4.329) &       & (-5.025) &       & (0.105) &       & (-3.444) &       & (-2.804) &       & (0.449) \\
Log GDP & 0.913\astiii & 0.840\astiii & 0.550\astiii & 0.475\astiii & -1.180\astiii & -1.239\astiii & 0.602\astii & 0.626\astiii & 0.522\astiii & 0.529\astiii & -1.492\astiii & -1.505\astiii \\
      & (2.922) & (3.529) & (2.960) & (3.008) & (-3.878) & (-3.778) & (2.570) & (2.893) & (2.913) & (3.324) & (-4.890) & (-3.976) \\
Debt/GDP  & 0.004\astiii & 0.004\astiii & 0.002\astii & 0.002\astii & 0.004\asti & 0.004\asti & 0.003\astiii & 0.003\astiii & 0.002\astii & 0.002\astii & 0.003 & 0.003 \\
      & (2.836) & (2.861) & (1.981) & (1.975) & (1.775) & (1.764) & (2.657) & (2.689) & (2.062) & (2.075) & (1.540) & (1.566) \\
Reserve/Debt  & 0.069\astii & 0.071\astii & 0.043\astii & 0.045\astii & 0.075\astii & 0.073\astii & 0.051\astiii & 0.053\astiii & 0.036\astiii & 0.037\astiii & 0.057\astii & 0.055\astii \\
      & (2.512) & (2.372) & (2.130) & (1.964) & (2.405) & (2.367) & (2.974) & (3.099) & (2.746) & (2.803) & (2.204) & (2.202) \\
Term Spread  & 0.042\astiii & 0.042\astiii & 0.038\astiii & 0.037\astiii & 0.012 & 0.015\astii & 0.012\astiii & 0.010\astiii & 0.009\astiii & 0.008\astiii & -0.003 & -0.002 \\
      & (6.331) & (6.990) & (7.131) & (7.323) & (1.330) & (1.985) & (4.036) & (4.962) & (3.790) & (5.111) & (-0.248) & (-0.186) \\
VSTOXX  & 0.004\astiii & 0.004\astiii & 0.003\astiii & 0.003\astiii & 0.008\astiii & 0.008\astiii & 0.003\astiii & 0.003\astiii & 0.001\astiii & 0.001\astiii & 0.007\astiii & 0.007\astiii \\
      & (4.920) & (4.380) & (4.450) & (3.916) & (7.650) & (8.089) & (6.285) & (6.200) & (3.514) & (3.497) & (5.211) & (6.388) \\
\\
Bank fixed eff. & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes}   & \mc{Yes} \\
No.\ of obs. & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620}   & \mc{620} \\
Adjusted $R^2$ & 0.728 & 0.720 & 0.774 & 0.761 & 0.822 & 0.822 & 0.718 & 0.721 & 0.772 & 0.774 & 0.784 & 0.785 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%

\smallskip
Remark: All independent variables except $\log\text{GDP}$ measured in \%.
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
%    \end{table}%
%
%    \end{landscape}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 I was going to suggest the data ought to be aligned as digits but gav eup once I shrank it enough:-)

Comment: @Mico Just a quick question. Currently my table is rotated by 180 how can I rotate it so that it looks like the one in your post? I have edited my post with the rotation of my table

Comment: @TrueTears -- Try to recompile the document once or twice more; that will probably help restore the orientation of the table.

Comment: @Mico Hmm very weird, I've tried compiling it a few times, it still remains in the current orientation. Is there possibly a rotation command I can use to rotate it?

Comment: To add on... I realised for some reason when the table appears on an odd numbered page, it appears as the orientation shown in your post, however whenever the table is on an even numbered page, it reverts to mine.

Comment: @TrueTears - Are you using a document class with two-side page mode? If so, the orientation of landscape-mode pages will change depending on whether the page is verso (even-numbered) or recto (odd-numbered). Just load the `rotating` package with either the `figuresright` or `figuresleft` option, depending on which orientation you prefer.

Comment: @Mico Ah yes you're right, I am using a two-sided page document so that's why it was changing orientation depending on page number. `figuresright` did the trick, thank you!