# How to make a longtable (set as landscape) fit a landscape page

Tags: tables

I have a longtable set as a landscape, but it is too wide. I want to resize the table and have it fit a standard landscape page. Typically I do this with `\resizebox` but the longtable package will not let me do that.  I also have a \footnote{} in a longtable set as landscape, but the footnote shows up as if in a portrait document. How do you make the footnote length fit a landscape page? Any guidance here will be tremendously appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: Better to use `ltablex` (functionalities of longtable brought to `tabularx`; you'll control the total width of the table. You also can play with the font size, and the intercolumn spacing (`\tabcolsep` or `\arraycolsep`).

Comment: using scaling on any table is just so horrible and should only ever be done as a last resort, just use a suitable font size (eg `\footnotesize`) before the table and use column widths `p{1cm}`  that fit in the space.

Comment: see for example http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/133425/how-to-make-this-table-fit-on-a-landscape-page?rq=1 which is tabular rather than longtable but the ways to control the width are the same or more or less all of the questions in the "related" list on the right